# About tkinter directory path

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to insert the path of the file in #here! but my terminal spends name 'dirname' is not defined message :(...

I don't know why that error occurs.. I elide some codes :)... Thank you for reading

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

def ask():
    dirname = filedialog.askopenfile(
        initialdir='C:/Users/PC/Desktop',
        title='파일 선택',
        filetypes=(('png 파일','*.png'), ('jpg 파일', '*jpg'), ('모든 파일 보기', '*.*'))
    )
    filename = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
    Txt.configure(text='경로 :' + dirname.name)

def ocr():
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(#here!), lang="kor")
    print(text)

Txt = Label(window, text = ' ')
Txt.pack()

path_button = Button(window, text="경로 선택하기", command = ask)
path_button.pack()

button = Button (window, width = 10, text = "선택하기", overrelief="solid", command = ocr) # 확인 버튼
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

In `ask()` you are setting to variables: `dirname` and `filename`.

These two variables are set as local variables by default (they will not be visible outside the `ask()` function). That's why you can't access them.

You can patch this by setting them to global:

```py
#AFTER THE IMPORTS
filename = "some_default_filename.png"
dirname = "/some/default/path/"

#INSERT THIS AT THE BEGINNING OF ASK()
def ask():
    global filename
    global dirname

    filename = ..... #Your code

#YOU WILL BE ABLE TO ACCESS THEM TO OCR()
def ocr():
    #.......
    Image.open(dirname + filename)
    #.......
```

Note that if you don't need to edit the variable, you don't need to declare it global, python will assume that by default. You can still add `global dirname` and `global filename` if you wish, the code will run as well.